# How to create a column with each number in a row 10 times smaller than the previous number?

Tags: r

I have to create a data frame with a column filled with runif numbers, but each number in a row is 10 times smaller than the previous one (this should be done 5 times). So, if the first number in a first row is 5, second is 0.5, 0.05, 0.005 and 0.0005 at the end. For example, in the code below, data frame has been made and I should replace first five values in OD column like explained above.

```
levels <- c("ref", "treat", "control")
x <- as.factor(labels)
a <- levels[x]
values <- runif(25,min=0,max=25)
my.data <- data.frame(labels = a, OD=values)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a detailed answer.
You'd like to make each number 10 times smaller than the previous,
Which can be done with something like:

```
runif(1, min=0, max=25) / 10 ^ (0:4)
```

We include 0 in the exponents to keep the original number.

Then you want to apply that operation to each value in `values`,
so you can use `sapply` for that.

```
sapply(values, "/", 10 ^ (0:4))
```

However, when each result is a vector, `sapply` binds them all column-wise,
so we transpose the result with `t`.
Since you want a data frame, you could simply end up with:

```
data.frame(labels=a, t(sapply(values, "/", 10 ^ (0:4))))
```

And maybe adjust column names afterwards with `colnames`.

BTW, your example is not reproducible, `labels` is not defined.

Comment: alternative to `sapply`  and transposing:  `data.frame(outer(values, 1/(10^(0:4))))`

Comment: Oh yes, I always forget `outer`. It could also be `outer(values, 10^(0:4), "/")`.